# Highcharts: enforce options when adding a serie with addSeries

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I try to enforce options while using addseries to add a serie to a chart that already has some series in it:

```
chart.addSeries( {
     "name"   : name,
     "data"   : data,
     "options": {
      dataGrouping: {
        forced: true,
         units : [ [ 'month', [ 1 ] ] ]
     }
   }
} );
```

In this case I try to enforce monthly grouping on the added serie, but the dataGrouping option is ignored.
How to properly enforce option when adding a serie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series config is not correct. There is no `'options'` property.
With the correct series object, data grouping works.

```
  "data": [10, 20, 20, 20, 40, 20],
  dataGrouping: {
    forced: true,
    units: [
      ['month', [1]]
    ]
  }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/61v2oyfd/